# How can i install LESS css on Reactjs App?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, less

I want to install LESS in react app. i have try and find solution to google but not success

I'm new in ReactJs also I don't have deep knowledge.

i need help someone who guide me to install less

**i have tried below example**

https://medium.com/@giordano.cardillo/adding-sass-or-less-support-to-create-react-app-38cbe6c370ce

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing? Error messages? Something not working after the installation?

Comment: there is not any error installation is successes but less fill is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Install and configure [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired).

Install `npm i -D customize-cra less less-loader`.

Add a `config-overrides.js` in your root with the following:

```
const { override, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  addLessLoader()
);
```

More info: https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra